# FlexSlider 2 caption flicker on chrome

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm having some flickering in my captions on chrome: http://tyni.cc/flexsliderissue
In safari everything runs fine.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Flexslider pretty regularly and also found the same problem. Setting the 'useCSS' property to 'false' fixed it for me. Didn't get to the bottom of why it was happening though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add these CSS properties to your listitem to fix it

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```