# Chrome shows html too late

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flexslider

I have made a slider, based on [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). The slider is working perfectly, except for Chrome. All latest versions of FF, IE, Safari work fine, but Chrome isn't. Normally it's the other-way around...

See my slider here: http://test.postitief.nl/slider/.

What you will see (I hope) is that the with transparency including the text is show after the animation is done. It doesn't slide with the animation. All other browser slide this text without a problem and immediately show it.

**Added video's**

- Video of how the slider should work (IE10): [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60346690/slider-oke.mp4)
- Video of how the slider works in Chrome (v29): [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60346690/slider-wrong.mp4)

**Added code**

`code` http://jsfiddle.net/zwFhe/

Comment: It looks like it works perfectly to me. I'm on Chrome 28.

Comment: There's a file linking problem with Canary 31.0.1607.1: `GET http://test.postitief.nl/slider/js/jquery.min.map 500 (Internal Server Error) ` and I can see the issue with the overlay text.

Comment: please post your source here and/or a fiddle/jsbin or other.  When external links decay, this question becomes worthless.

Comment: @JeffNoel: Is see the internet server error. No idea where that come's from, but will look at it!

Comment: Looking at it on the latest chrome(29) on OSX, looks perfect

Comment: fixed! Thanks all, see answer below from Bondye

Comment: Don't post junk in a code block when using jsfiddle - show an sscce in the question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

I found an [equal problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197437/flexslider-2-caption-flicker-on-chrome)

Solution: `useCSS: "false"`

### Tip

You have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

But I think you need to include the flexslider js file before your function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: `useCSS: false` did the trick! Seems like the problem is solved! Thanks!!!